# Angular6 Div around Arrays from same user

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular6

I have some Data for a Messenger:

```
public messages = [
    {
        direction: 'me', // Required
        user_id: 554, // Required
        user: 'Sven', // Optional
        avatar: 'urltoavatar', // Optional
        message: 'Hi du alter babbsack!' // Optional
    },
    {
        direction: 'others', // Required
        user_id: 8774, // Required
        user: 'Hannes', // Optional
        avatar: 'urltoavatar', // Optional
        message: 'Hey whats going on?' // Optional
    },
    {
        direction: 'others', // Required
        user_id: 8774, // Required
        user: 'Hannes', // Optional
        avatar: 'urltoavatar', // Optional
        message: 'No Idea bro! This ' // Optional
    }
];
```

I insert this inside the Messenger Message Area: `<mark6-messenger-message [messages]="messages" [avatarMe]="false" [avatarOthers]="true"></mark6-messenger-message>`

The View of the `<mark6-messenger-message>` :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages">
    <div class="msg" [ngClass]="message.direction">
        <div class="msg-avatar" *ngIf="(avatarMe && message.direction === 'me') || (avatarOthers && message.direction === 'others')">
            <img [src]="message.avatar" [alt]="message.user">
        </div>
        <div class="msg-content">
            <div class="msg-message">{{message.message}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

The Result is this in Browser: (I change the messages in Code, dont worry about this)

[image]

The problem is now that when 1 Person Spam some messages, i want to remove the avatars up from the latest message. and i want remove the space between the 2 messages from same person. Like this:

[image]

but of 2 different people write it must look like this:

[image]

its verry hard for me to figure out how to solve this. and all i ask tell me that there is no way without lost alot of performance. I need to do this in a way, that handle all this stuff automaticly only with the data `direction` and `user` (Which means username) or maybe i add a field for `user_id` then i have 2 required fields ( `direction` and `user_id` ) The goal is to make this so easy and automaticly as possible, because this is for the open source lib that i hope in future alot people will use. i dont want to force them to do to much logic stuff. :)

Here is the repository if you need to check other files or more informations: https://github.com/DevMonkeysDE/ngx-mark6/tree/master/projects/mark6-lib/src/lib/messenger

The best thing would be when every pack of messages each person get a div container, then i can work simply with css:first-child and css:last-child. but then it must transform on the fly every message the whole HTML DOM, this is maybe really very very Performance breaking.

Comment: I would do it with conditional CSS elements, like: take down the margin between messages and add a 'margin' div after each message, and add a conditional class to it which check if the user from this index and the past index is the same, than choose small margin class, if not, choose the large padding class, and the same thing with the avatar, if its the same user, dont show it.

Comment: Can you maybe make me a example for the conditions? I am so bad in this things... And you dont think that its better to wrap a div around messages from same direction and user? then i need only 1 logical condition and can do the rest with simple css (first and last-child) But i never saw before that someone wrap divs in realtime around elements. (maybe really to performance breaking)

Comment: You cant do it in css alone because nth:child css does not take conditions, so you cant match it with real time users, If not one will answer till I get home, Ill try to provide you with simple example.

Comment: If you have a good model, with a structure that matches with the view you want to generate, everything will be simpler. Your description shows that you don't want to display a list of messages. You want to display a list of message groups, where each group has 1-N subsequent messages, all posted by a single user. So, use TypeScript to create an array of message groups from your messages (by detecting subseqent messages posted by the same user). Then you can iterate through each group and display each group with a single avatar, and inside this group, iterate over the messages of the group.

Comment: @JBNizet , from his topic and images, it seems like he is implementing some kind of chat? So if its real time chat, running these grouping each time that new message will come, will take alot of resources. its better not to rely on the controller do this, since its only about the view.

Comment: Yeah i want to build a realtime chat that can use in big chatrooms over 200 people at same time. But the most important thing here is that i build a repo that is open for everyone, so it must be max customizable and bring the best experiance to the developers.

Comment: @dAxx_ So, you want to test, each time a message comes, if it belongs to the last group or in a new one. This is very very far from taking a lot of resources. Should just take a few nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are after can be accomplished by simply comparing current + next message direction in the ngFor loop and see if they are different then add a "last" or whatever you want to name it class. Because you essentially want the "last of this direction" message.

```
<div [class]="message.direction" [ngClass]="{last: messages[i+1] && messages[i+1].direction !== message.direction || isLast, message:true}"
 *ngFor="let message of messages; let isLast = last; let i = index;">
    {{message.message}}
</div>
```

1. `[class]="message.direction"`

This will give us the direction of the message as a class `me` or `others` in your case, pretty straight forward.

Now let me explain the "last" class part:

2. `*ngFor="let message of messages; let isLast = last; let i = index;"`

The ngFor directive exposes some local variables like `last`, `first,`, `index`, so we can take advantage of that and assign our `isLast` variable to `last` local variable from ngFor loop, at same time our `i` variable will hold the current `index` ngFoor loop. [Docs for ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)

3. `[ngClass]="{last: messages[i+1] && messages[i+1].direction !== message.direction || isLast, message:true}`

We use the ngClass directive to apply `last` class if our condition is true, in this case condition is just comparing if the next message in the loop (`messages[i+1].direction`) is not the same as current message in the loop `message.direction`. The only problem with this is the very last message in the loop `messages[i+1]` will be `undefined`, and that's where the or `|| isLast` check comes thru, as this will always be true for last message in the loop. [Docs for ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

As an aside, `messages[i+1] && messages[i+1].direction` you need to do it this way so you short circuit your condition check direction only if `messages[i+1]` is defined, otherwise your code will crash on the last item. [You can read more about that in the Javascript docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation)

For showing/hiding avatars, that's just simple css once you have the `last` class in there.

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwqqee

Hope that helps.

EDIT: I forgot you have more than two users, but same concept applies, just check user_id instead of direction, see updated example.

```
[ngClass]="{
  'message': true,
  'last-from-direction': messages[i+1] && messages[i+1].direction !== message.direction || isLast,
  'last-from-user': messages[i+1] && messages[i+1].user_id !== message.user_id || isLast
  }"
```

Comment: Thank you alot for this detailed explaination and the awesome stackbliz! This helped me alot to reach exactly that what i want to reach.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution would be to make the `*ngIf` condition a little more complicated.

Modify the `*ngFor` directive to keep track of the index of messages like so: `*ngFor="let message of messages; let i=index"`

Then you could try something like `*ngIf="(avatarMe && message.direction === 'me' && (messages[i+1].direction !== 'me') || (avatarOthers && message.direction === 'others' && (messages[i+1].user_id !== message.user_id))"`, to show the avatar **only if the next message is not from the same user**.

However, it might not work for the last message as it won't find `messages[i+1]`.

Another solution would be to modify, if possible, the `messages` array's data structure to include the `timestamp` (since its a messaging app, it makes more sense to keep track of time). Then we could order by timestamp and show the avatar with the message with greatest timestamp.

Comment: That make sense with the timestamp, but how i modify the other things like margins and border-radius? for all this would be for me the simpelst solution, when message groups have a div around. but you think this is because the performance no option right?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the `div` with `class="msg-content"` is responsible for showing the gray rounded box containing the message. If that is the case, why not use `[ngClass]="{msg-content: <<condition for NOT showing avatar>>, msg-content2: <<condition for showing avatar>>}"`, where msg-content2 is a different class with the different borders?

Comment: The avatar is in a div with class `msg-avatar` on the same DOM level as the div with `msg-content` If there is no way to wrap with a `message group div` then i need conditions on alot elements. on `msg-avatar` to hide the avatar if not last message, on `msg-content` to change the borders. (first remove border radius bottom, middle divs remove all border radius and last post remove top border radius:..) and on div with class `msg` to change the margin around the messages... Thats alot logic... a div that work as message group would make everything alot easyer beacuse then i can do all with css.

Comment: Its a trade-off: either you modify your data structure, to make the template simpler, or keep your data structure simple and complicate the template with a lot of logic. My advice would be to go with @JBNizet 's suggestion to group messages coming from the same user. However, I can't see how you can distinguish between user A's messages (numbered for eg: 1,2,3) where another user B's message came before A's message no.3. In that case you'll need timestamp to group A's `[1,2]` and `[3]` separately. I'm not sure if there's any other way to directly wrap with a message group `div`.

Comment: You can have one div ontop and one on bottom which is divider with fixed margin, if its the same user above you dont apply the style, other than that you do, same for bottom just check for the next message. I will suggest to make a new component or directive for each message which will handle all this logic with much more order and simplicity.